# Prepare for segue to a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I am having troubles with preparing for a segue to a navigation controller which is controlling a second table view controllers navigation bar. [image: This is the storyboard]

Anyway, I need to transfer an array to the next table view controller and this is the code I am using to do it (This code appears on the first table view controller):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
            // pass data to next view
            let indexpath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            let DestinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerTableViewController
            var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo : [Answer]
            var ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = levelsArray.map( { $0.AnswersArray })
            ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements[indexpath.row]
            DestinationViewController.ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo
        }
    }
```

When I click on a cell I get the SIGABRT error on this line:

```
let DestinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerTableViewController
```

I know why it does this (because the cast I made is to the table view not the navigation controller)
How can I transfer data to that second table view while keeping the navigation bar.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Any reason you are pushing from one navigation controller to another? Seems like the second navigation controller is unnecessary

Comment: Reason being that I am trying to get my cancel button to work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let NavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController
let DestinationViewController = NavigationController.topViewController as! AnswerTableViewController
// ...
DestinationViewController.ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElements = ArrayofArrayswithAnswerElementsTwo
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the second navigation controller, your code looks fine. The segue should be a push segue from "Your Lists" to "Content", if you push, it will not need another navigation controller, but the bar will still show. Navigation bars will cascade down the navigation stack.

More info:

[UINavigationController Apple Doc and Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/)

[Ray Wenderlich Storyboard and Nav Controller Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)